# Ahem.ttf needed by 'test_fonts/Ahem.ttf' is missing and no known rule to make it

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to compile CEF locally on my Ubuntu 20.10 machine and I'm currently stuck on the last step - compiling it. When I run `ninja -C out/Debug_GN_x64 cef chrome_sandbox` inside chromium/cef, it gives me an error that even Google doesn't know about.

```
user@userpc:~/code/chromium_git/chromium/src$ ninja -C out/Debug_GN_x64 cef chrome_sandbox
ninja: Entering directory `out/Debug_GN_x64'
ninja: error: '../../third_party/test_fonts/test_fonts/Ahem.ttf', needed by 'test_fonts/Ahem.ttf', missing and no known rule to make it
```

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a result of `automate-git.py` failing before. Redoing all the steps in a VM solved the issue.